# Same Function Running Parallel will override values?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am Using same function from many places...

for example below function

```
Public Sub getUser(ByVal Name as string)
      dim myName=Name
         .......
      insert(myName)
End Sub
```

I am using this function from so many places...
I have doubt should this function override this myName values with latest function call?

Suppose i called getUser("ABC") so value of myName is now ABC now sudden all call getUser("XYZ") so at insert(myName) will it insert("ABC") or insert("XYZ")??

I need it to be insert("ABC") and then insert("XYZ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use locking to make sure only one thread does something at a time

```
//declare an object for locking
Dim lockObjcect As New [Object]()

    Public Sub getUser(ByVal Name as string)
        SyncLock lockObjcect
          dim myName=Name
              .......
          insert(myName)
        End SyncLock
    End Sub
```

With the locking, now only one thread will be able to execute the code between `SyncLock and End SyncLock` this means First `ABC` will be inserted and then `XYZ` will be inserted

Comment: Thanks Haris.. What to Provide in someLock above

Comment: here `some` class represent any object. Any object can be used for locking purposes. It is a good practise to declare a separate object for locking purposes. Just make an object of Object Class. See the update answer

Comment: Thanks broth but what i ask should happen?? Will it override or not??

Comment: With the locking now only one thread will be able to execute the code between `SyncLock` and `End SyncLock` this means First ABC will be inserted and then XYZ will be inserted